# How to create a flag that increments by 1 based on conditions

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

How can I create a flag by looking at values of consecutive variables?

For example, in the table(image) below,

For **row#1**, flag takes the value 1;

For **row#2** onwards it checks:

```
  If variable1 =lag(variable2) 
 and variable2=lag(variable1) then flag = lag(flag) else flag increments by 1.
```

In this case, the condition doesn’t match therefore the flag takes value 2.

For **row#3**:
   Since it matches the above condition flag is same as 2

For **row#4:** Even though it matches the above condition, the flag changes to 3 as the previous 2 rows(row#2 &row#3) have already been matched

And so on..

The final flag will look like:

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that you better have your input data sorted to implement a "moving flag" with 2-row-based aggregation. For this answer's sake I've added a `row_number()` function to generate the order in which your sample data is given.

**Test data**

```
create table flagtest( var1 text, var2 text);
insert into flagtest(var1,var2) values 
  ('T','Z'),('B','A'),('A','B'),('B','A'),('A','B'),('A','B'),
  ('A','B'),('B','A'),('C','D'),('E','F'),('F','E'),('M','N');
```

**Code**

```
-- fourth part
select var1, var2, sum(change_flag_2_based) over (order by ordcol) as flag
from( -- third part
  select *, 
    case when 
      lag(change_flag) over (order by ordcol) = 0
      and lag(change_flag, 2) over (order by ordcol) = 1
      then 1 else change_flag 
    end as change_flag_2_based
  from ( -- second part
    select
      var1, var2, ordcol,
      case when 
        var1 = lag(var2) over (order by ordcol) and 
        var2 = lag(var1) over (order by ordcol) 
        then 0 else 1 
      end as change_flag 
    from ( -- first part
      select var1, var2, row_number() over () as ordcol
      from flagtest
      ) ordered_data
    ) prep_aggr_all
  ) prep_aggr_two_rows_based;
```

**How does it work?**

- First part is all about providing a column to order the input data later in window functions. This will be any other column that you currently have in your table. In the example it introduces `row_number()` window function to generate such numerical order.
- Second part is where we are marking rows, with assumed strategy of cross-equals between two variables comparing current with previous row, with indicators 1 and 0 whether the flag should change in this particular row. This is not a 2-based pair aggregation (yet).
- Third part introduces comparing current row change flag indicator with indicators from two previous rows and if 1 row behind doesn't change the flag and 2 rows behind does change it it means that we should mark current row as flag-changing (2-row-based flag).
- Fourth part is just for moving sum which makes final flags by summing those groups.

**Output**

```
 var1 | var2 | flag
------+------+------
 T    | Z    |    1
 B    | A    |    2
 A    | B    |    2
 B    | A    |    3
 A    | B    |    3
 A    | B    |    4
 A    | B    |    5
 B    | A    |    5
 C    | D    |    6
 E    | F    |    7
 F    | E    |    7
 M    | N    |    8
```

Comment: Of course the order of a table's rows is not fixed, but that's a problem of the question, not the answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe exactly. I've mentioned it at the beginning since there is something missing :-)